# Calculating Eta Squared in R for repeated measures

Tags: r, anova

I'm using the `aov()` function to perform a repeated measures ANOVA using R, e.g. as at http://personality-project.org/r/r.anova.html site.

```
datafilename <- "http://personality-project.org/r/datasets/R.appendix4.data"
data.ex4 <- read.table(datafilename, header=TRUE)   
data.ex4
```

Calculating a standard ANOVA allows to use the `etaSquared()` function from the `lsr` package or alternatively the `etasq()` function from `heplots`:

```
aov.standard=aov(Recall~(Task*Valence),data.ex4 ) 
etaSquared(aov.standard)
etasq(aov.standard)
```

However, when implementing a within subjects model, both functions fail to recognize the linear object model.

```
aov.within=aov(Recall~(Task*Valence)+Error(Subject/(Task*Valence)),data.ex4 )
etaSquared(aov.within)
etasq(aov.within)
```

Has anyone got an easy solution for this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the `ezANOVA` function from the `ez` package, the eta-squared is automatically calculated:

```
library(ez)

m1 <- ezANOVA(data = data.ex4, dv = Recall, wid = Subject, within = .(Task,Valence), type = 3, detailed = TRUE)
m1$ANOVA
```

This gives the following output:

```
        Effect DFn DFd    SSn       SSd          F           p p<.05         ges
1  (Intercept)   1   4 4177.2 349.13333 47.8579339 0.002291098     * 0.910303347
2         Task   1   4   30.0  16.33333  7.3469388 0.053508297       0.067934783
3      Valence   2   8    9.8  26.86667  1.4590571 0.288250073       0.023255814
4 Task:Valence   2   8    1.4  19.26667  0.2906574 0.755343673       0.003389831
```

The `ges` column has the generalized eta-squared values you need.